# Connecting Proximity Sensors to computer

Tags: sockets, sensors

I'm asking without knowing anything about this. How can I connect two PNP Proximity Sensors to the computer via Ethernet and receive a signal? Is it possible to connect such sensors based on IP? Then I want to read socket. thanks

Comment: Seems like something that is entirely dependent on the sensors themselves and what kind of hardware I/O ports they provide. Do they even provide Ethernet ports? Do they support IP communication? Via TCP/UDP? Do you have any documentation on them at all? Your question is quite too broad to answer as-is.

Comment: If there is a special sensor for the tcp/ip connection, I can supply it. I can find out if there is an intermediary board to connect the digital sensors to the computer. I'm trying to understand based on advice.

Comment: Again, too broad to answer. And asking for any recommendations of which boards to use would be off-topic for StackOverflow anyway. This is a Q&A site about programming, but you are asking a hardware question instead.